# Content By Search Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, content-search-web-part

I am looking into the differences between SharePoint 2016 Standard and Enterprise.

Is the Content By Search Webpart in SharePoint Server 2016 still a Enterprise Webpart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in SharePoint 2016 Content by Search Webpart is still part of Enterprise edition.Click on below link to get more information

[Feature availability across SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx)

Comment: It says seardh webparts = Enterprise. I guess Core Script Result WP does not fall in this category